# Python Pyramid unit testcase Dummyrequest: needs to convert file path to "webob.compat.cgi_FieldStorage"

Tags: python, api, pyramid

I have created following API in pyramid.

```
@view_config(route_name="/demo", renderer="json", request_method="POST")
    def file_attachment(self):
        file = self.request.POST['file']
        file_content = file.file
        file_content.seek(0)
```

API takes `username` and `form-data: file` as an input.

I am creating unit testcase for this API using `pyramid.testing.Dummyrequest` as follows:

```
def test_img_attach_success(self):
    input_data = {
        "username": "testuser@gmail.com",
        "file": "/tmp/test_inputs/demo_img.png"
        }
    self.collab.request =  testing.DummyRequest(POST=input_data, dbsession=self.session)
    response = self.collab.file_attachment()
```

in testcase I am passing value of `file` as a string. but type of `file` variable in `file_attachment` function taking `webob.compat.cgi_FieldStorage`.

So I am getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'file'`.

How can I convert `str` to `webob.compat.cgi_FieldStorage`?

Comment: You expect `file_content = file.file` to get a file with a file attribute (`file.file`), but you pass that key a string via `"file": "/tmp/test_inputs/demo_img.png"`. Instead pass it a file object.

Comment: @StevePiercy even `file` object dont have `.file` functionality. when I check `type(self.request.POST['file'])` , it gave `webob.compat.cgi_FieldStorage`